# wxPython Can't change font

Tags: python, wxpython

I am trying to get the system font, modify it a bit and then set to a static text:

```
panel = wx.Panel(self)

font = wx.SystemSettings.GetFont(wx.SYS_SYSTEM_FONT)
font.SetPointSize(20)

vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

hbox1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
class_name_text = wx.StaticText(panel, label='Class name')
class_name_text.SetFont(font)
hbox1.Add(class_name_text)

vbox.Add(hbox1)

panel.SetSizer(vbox)
```

But apparently the text still remains with point size 12 (it looks that). However, when i print the point size before and after changing it seems to be ok (12 before - 20 after). A have tried to create my own font and changing its properties - in that case everything works. What is wrong?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but perhaps you have to set the Font before you set the label.  Have you tried calling SetLabel() after calling SetFont()?

Comment: No, this doesn't work. Although when instead of wx.SystemSettings.GetFont(wx.SYS_SYSTEM_FONT) I use something like wx.Font(12, ...), i.e. creating the font manually, and then font.SetPointSizer(20), the font succesfully changes its point size. In the documentation it's written that wx.SystemSettings.GetFont method returns a wx.Font object, which means that it should behave just like the one, which i create manually. But it doesnt.. And as i see, SetUnderlined and others work. The problem is in SetPixel/PointSize

Comment: Does it have to be System Font?  Are you really just trying to get the default font for the control?  Because if so, maybe you should use wx.FontInfo() instead.

Comment: Use `Layout()`  after changing the font https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Window.html#wx.Window.Layout

Answer (score 0):

Well, thanks everyone! It seems that my system font, which `wx.SystemSettings.GetFont(wx.SYS_SYSTEM_FONT)` returned, was a bit strange, because it didn't support any more sizes, but default. When i changed font itself with `SetFaceName` method, `SetPointSize` began working. So, the problem was in my system, probably in the system font particulary